# /stats/air/operators/{operator_id}/export の動作について

Tags: soracom

https://dev.soracom.io/jp/docs/api/ から /stats/air/operators/{operator_id}/export を実行したときにResponse Code: 500 が返ってきました。

Response Body:

```
{
  "code": "COM0003",
  "message": "Internal server error. message:400 Bad Request"
}
```

**実行時のパラメータ**
URL: https://api.soracom.io/v1/stats/air/operators/{自分のOperatorID}/export
body:

```
{
  "from": 1443657600, // 2015年10月01日0時0分
  "period": "month", 
  "to": 1446335940   // 2015年10月31日23時59分
}
```

**利用状況**
 - 指定したOperatorIDに関連するSIMカードは１枚
 - SIMカードは登録のみ（データ通信は１度も行ったことがない）の状態

**質問**

1. Response Code: 500 になるのは正しい動きなのでしょうか？
2. Response Code: 500 が間違っている場合は、どのような動作になるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subscriber の groupId に実在しない ID が設定されている場合に /stats API が同様のエラーを返す場合があるようです。こちらはその問題に該当するかもしれません。

本来は /subscriber/set_group API が実在しない ID を受け付けないようになっている必要があるのですが、そのチェック処理が抜けており、実在しない ID も受け付けるようになってしまっているためにこの問題が起こってしまうようです。

この件はおって修正させていただきますが、バックエンドの修正となるため少々時間を要します。

それまでの回避策としましては、いったん unset_group API にて groupId を null としていただくことで /stats API のエラーが起きなくなるものと思われます。

こちらをお試しいただくことはできますでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。指摘いただいた  /subscriber/set_group 実行後、同じ手順で /stats/air/operators/{operator_id}/export を実行したところ、リファレンスの通り、200 とダウンロード元のURLを取得することができました。